# @react-pdf/renderer how to check the loading state of the document?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, react-pdf

so im generating a pdf using some data and rendering the pdf with the PDFViewer, but im generating more than 10 pages and i want to show a loading state before the document generated, i cannot find anything related to loading state, im I missing something ??? here is my component

```
<PDFViewer width={1000} height={1000}>
            <Document>
                {products &&
                    chunks.map((ele, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                                <View style={styles.container}>
                                    <View style={styles.head}>
                                        <View style={styles.head1}>
                                            <Text style={styles.title}>Pharmacie Salim</Text>
                                            <View style={styles.headCard}>
                                                <Image
                                                    style={styles.image}
                                                    src={require("../assets/phone-icon.png").default}
                                                />
                                                <Text style={styles.cardText}>05 30 50 05 00</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.headCard}>
                                                <Image
                                                    style={styles.image}
                                                    src={require("../assets/email-icon.png").default}
                                                />
                                                <Text style={styles.cardText}>demointern@sobrus.com</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.headCard}>
                                                <Image
                                                    style={styles.image}
                                                    src={require("../assets/gps-icon.png").default}
                                                />
                                                <Text style={styles.cardText}>Villa No 222, Rue Tetouan</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.head2}>
                                            <Text style={styles.type}>
                                                Chiffre d'affaires par famille tarifaire (Catégorie et TVA)
                                            </Text>
                                            <View style={styles.head2Cards}>
                                                <View style={styles.headCard}>
                                                    <Image
                                                        style={styles.image2}
                                                        src={require("../assets/timer-icon.png").default}
                                                    />

                                                    <View style={styles.cardInfo}>
                                                        <Text style={styles.cardTextHead}>Période</Text>
                                                        <Text style={styles.cardTextBody}>
                                                            De 2021-03-02 à 2021-04-05
                                                        </Text>
                                                    </View>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.headCard}>
                                                    <Image
                                                        style={styles.image2}
                                                        src={require("../assets/printer-icon.png").default}
                                                    />
                                                    <View style={styles.cardInfo}>
                                                        <Text style={styles.cardTextHead}>Imprimé le</Text>
                                                        <Text style={styles.cardTextBody}>2021-03-02</Text>
                                                    </View>
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.table}>
                                        <View style={styles.rowHeader}>
                                            <View style={styles.colFirst}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Période</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>No de transaction</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Client</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Total avant remise</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Remise</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Total</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Non payé</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.col}>
                                                <Text style={styles.th}>Gestionnaire</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                        {ele.map((prod) => (
                                            <View style={styles.row}>
                                                <View style={styles.colFirst}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>{prod.name}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>{prod.purchase_price}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>{prod.salePrice}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>{prod.supplier?.name}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>Remise</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>Total</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>Non payé</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.col}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.th}>Gestionnaire</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                        ))}
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </Page>
                        );
                    })}
            </Document>
        </PDFViewer>
```

so how can i show a loader before the document finish rendering ?

Comment: i dont want to know how long a pdf will take to render, i just wanna show a loading gif or text before it completely renders, so how can i do that ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div style={{position:"relative"}}>
            <div style={{margin: "auto",fontSize:"2rem", color:"#000",width:"100%",height:"70vh",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>Your loading message...</div>
            <PDFViewer showToolbar={false} style={{width:"100%",height:"100%",height:"70vh",border:"none",backgroundColor:"transparent",position:"absolute",left:"0",top:"0"}} >
                //Your content
            </PDFViewer>
        </div>
```